# Why alcoholic beverages packaging do not contain information about nutritional values and calories?

Tags: nutrition, diet, alcohol

Majority of the food sold in the UK contain nutritional values, how much of a daily intake, how many calories, all that stuff.

Alcohol, on the other hand, doesn't contain such information. Given that beer is very frequent addition to the diet it should be clear what is getting into a body.

My theory is that nutritional value is plausible *(very low)* and if people knew that what inside they would think twice and the sales figures would decrease. Does it have any backing in consensual reality?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about packaging laws, not health.

Comment: This is both not really about health, and localized. For example, in the US it's because alcohol falls under a different regulatory bureau than food items.

Comment: Definitely off topic but it raises the interesting question of just how hard  alcohol manufacturers would oppose adding calorie contents to their labels. I do think most people would be shocked at how caloric alcohol is.